# TChart : Get mark style with series title together with its value

Tags: delphi-xe2, teechart

I have bar series in which I want to set the marks style that contains both the series title and the actual value of the bar. Here's my code :

```
procedure TFRDept.PopulateDeptChart;
var
    Loop ,YearIndex: integer;
    DeptKey: String;
    StartBar, TotalBar, EndBar : TBarSeries;
begin

    for Loop := 0  to FDeptList.Count -1 do
    begin
        DeptKey := FDeptList.ValueFromIndex[Loop];

        StartBar :=  GetInsertedBarSeries(DeptKey+'Start', 'Start', clGreen);
        TotalBar :=  GetInsertedBarSeries(DeptKey+'Total', 'Total', clBlue);
        EndBar   :=  GetInsertedBarSeries(DeptKey+'End', 'End', clRed);

        with Dataset do
        begin
            if Locate('o_deptaddressno',DeptKey,[]) then
            begin

                While (FieldByName('o_deptaddressno').AsString = DeptKey) and not eof do
                begin

                    StartBar.AddXY(FieldByName('o_year').AsInteger,
                                                FieldByName('o_totalstart').AsInteger,
                                                FieldByName('o_year').AsString,
                                                StartBar.Color);


                   {when adding series per year for each department - the bars are not one after the other}
                    //TotalBar := GetInsertedBarSeries(DeptKey+'Total'+FieldByName('o_year').AsString, siLang.GetTextOrDefault('IDS_TOTAL'), clBlue);

                    TotalBar.AddXY(FieldByName('o_year').AsInteger,
                                                    FieldByName('o_total').AsInteger,
                                                    FieldByName('o_year').AsString,
                                                    TotalBar.Color);

                    TotalBar.Title := FieldByName('o_total').AsString + ': '+ FDeptList.Names[Loop];
                    TotalBar.Marks.Style := smsSeriesTitle;
                    TotalBar.Marks.ArrowLength := 50;
                    TotalBar.Marks.Callout.ArrowHead := ahSolid;


                    EndBar.AddXY(FieldByName('o_year').AsInteger,
                                                FieldByName('o_totalEnd').AsInteger,
                                                FieldByName('o_year').AsString,
                                                EndBar.Color);

                    Next;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;

    SetSeriesLegendProperties;
end;

function TFRDept.GetInsertedBarSeries(aName, aTitle: String;
  aColor: TColor): TBarSeries;
begin
    Result := TBarSeries.Create(Self);

    with Result do
    begin
        Name := 'Series' + aName;
        Title := aTitle;
        Color := aColor;
        Marks.Style := smsValue;
    end;

    Chart1.AddSeries(Result);
end;
```

My code generates the following bar but the values for the blue bar are not getting the appropriate values in the marks.

[image]
Actually, my goal is to display the respective departments above each series of bars(red,green and blue). I even opted for an alternative way by trying to modify the legend with 'symbols on draw' but the event didn't trigger. Is there a possibility to display the symbols in the legend of style lsSeriesGroups with checkboxes? Then I could also set the Totalbar :

```
Marks.Symbol.Visible :=  True;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me using this code:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self)).FillSampleValues();
    Chart1[i].Marks.Style:=smsValue;
    Chart1[i].Title:='Series'+IntToStr(i);
    Chart1[i].OnGetMarkText := Series1GetMarkText;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Series1GetMarkText(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer; var MarkText: String);
begin
  MarkText := MarkText + ' ' + Sender.Title;
end;
```

> I even opted for an alternative way by trying to modify the legend
>   with 'symbols on draw' but the event didn't trigger.

Did you assgin it? For example:

```
  Chart1.Legend.Symbol.OnDraw:=LegendDraw;
```

There's a complete example at *All Features\Welcome!\Miscellanoeus\Legend\Symbol OnDraw* in the features demo available at TeeChart's program group.

> Is there a possibility to display the symbols in the legend of style
>   lsSeriesGroups with checkboxes? Then I could also set the Totalbar :

I'm afraid this is not supported. Please feel free to add your features requests at [Steema Software's bugzilla](http://bugs.teechart.net/). The code snippet above produces this chart for me:

[image: bars with value and title marks]

Comment: Yes . Thanks loads . It works.  I added a second image to explain the second possibility that I was trying out in order to display the departments(series groups)

Comment: @Veela ok. That's not possible, I'm afraid. I have extended my reply a little bit.